# Adding Row click event or a check box to each of the rows in a SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS. These may be very trivial questions.
I've a SSRS report, which shows employees in row by row format. Is there any way that I can double click on a row and get the corresponding employeeID of the row. And another question is can I have check boxes in each of the rows so that I can do something based on the rows that was checked? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question regarding dynamically hiding and showing the employeeid, you would want to use the Visibility property on the employeeid column,row or textbox and set visibility to "HIDE" and check "Display can be toggled by this report item"  This will allow you to interactive show/hide the data.

[image: textbox visibilty]

Toggled Item Example

[image: Toggled Item]

Another quick and easy option would be to set the tooltip property of one of the employee textboxes to

```
=Fields!EmployeeID.Value
```

This would give you the employeeid without clicking anything, just hovering over the field.

For your second question about checkboxes, the easy answer is no, it's not built-in to do that.  But I have seen interactive "game" reports that run stored procedures to update data as you click on textboxes (which you could make to appear as checkboxes) and drill-through to itself to show refreshed data, but it's more of a hack than actual functionality.  Here's a link to one of the examples I've seen.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/05/20/multi-player-gaming-in-rs-aka-bi-power-hour-2008.aspx